# How to reset all gnome-tweak-tool settings to defaults

Tags: 14.04, unity, gnome, window

I have installed `gnome-tweak-tool` in Ubuntu 14.04 Unity, then chose *Windows* -> *Windows action keys* -> *Disabled* (previously was *Alt*). After that Unity windows buttons stopped working for that Ubuntu user.

I wonder how could I make buttons work as previously. I tried uninstalling `gnome-tweak-tool`, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a super easy solution.

Reinstall gnome-tweak-tool with

`sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool`

Run Tweak Tool

choose Windows and change the setting for Windows action keys from Disabled to <kbd>ALT</kbd>

[image: WindowTweaks]

This will undo the change you made and make the buttons work as they did previously.

Comment: I tried it. When I set _Windows action keys_ to ```ALT```, nothing happends. I see some kind of Python exception in terminal. After this I tried to log out and in, the option is again set to ```Disabled```.

Comment: Sorry, I ran Tweak Tool through the GUI so I didn't see anything in the terminal. I'll try it your way **if** you will be so kind as to define "some kind of Python exception". Perhaps the exact error message would be more useful than just the indication that there is an error.

Comment: Well, I could not reproduce the problem. This fix works for me now. The exception I mentioned occurred on ```gnome-tweak-tool``` startup and was: ```WARNING : Error detecting shell
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtweak/tweaks/tweak_group_shell_extensions.py", line 284, in __init__
    raise Exception("Shell not running or DBus service not available")
Exception: Shell not running or DBus service not available```

Comment: I'm glad it's resolved now. I got a similar response trying to run in a terminal (I think this is common when attempting to run GUI based apps from the CLI)

Answer (score 5):

Actually, you can simply open GNOME-tweak-tool (in GNOME), and click on its icon in the top panel. You should see an option that says "Reset to Defaults."

Comment: I cannot see this option. Where is it?

Answer (score 2):

I followed [the jrg guide how to reset GNOME to its defaults](http://www.faqoverflow.com/askubuntu/56313.html). I simply had to execute this command in terminal:

```
rm -rf .gnome .gnome2 .gconf .gconfd .metacity .cache .dbus .dmrc .mission-control .thumbnails ~/.config/dconf/user ~.compiz*
```

And Unity windows buttons started working properly.

Answer (score 0):

One can recover from that by running the following command:

```
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/wm/preferences/mouse-button-modifier "'<Alt>'"
```